# Solving differential equations with GPU?

Tags: differential-equations, gpu

I have a complicated differential equation which is taking a lot of time to solve, if I had more cores it would be easier, but my computer is limited...

I was wondering: is it possible to solve differential equations with GPU's?

Comment: PDE or ODE or vector ODE? Maybe you should look into [this](https://github.com/rtqichen/torchdiffeq).